# Can't get fid of the saved file after file_save_data

Tags: 7, files

I have been trying to get the fid of the file which my custom module is saving and every time I end up getting the error "Trying to get property of non-object in report()". I have tried file_object->id() and file_object-> fid ->value but neither are working. This is my code in .module file:

```
function file_write($source , $name) {

$uri =  file_default_scheme() . '://'.$name.'.txt';

$file_object = file_save_data($source, $uri, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
return $file_object;
}
```

And this is where how I call it and try to get fid:

```
$file_object = file_write($source, $name);
$fid = $file_object->fid->value;
```

Is there anything wrong with the code?
I also tried using other methods, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, `$file_object->fid` should work.

Looking at the code you have tried (`$file_object->fid->value`, `file_object->id()`), I guess you have been mixing up Drupal 8 and Drupal 7 documentation.